# Rails 4 application no css when printing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I need to print an order into PDF. I am using pdfkit gem. Absolutely exhausted but its just not printing any css.

application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"%>
```

order_controller.rb

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf {
    html = render_to_string(:template => "show.html.erb")
    kit = PDFKit.new(html)
    kit.stylesheets << "http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/application.css" <-- hardcoded this 
    send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "test_pdf", :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => 'attachment')

    return
  }
```

config/initializers/pdfkit.rb

```
  PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = 'Gem/Path/to/wkhtmltopdf'
  config.default_options = {
     :page_size => 'Legal',
     :print_media_type => true
  }
  # Use only if your external hostname is unavailable on the server.
  config.root_url = "http://localhost"
  config.verbose = false
end
```

application.rb

```
   config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware", :print_media_type => true
```

mime_types.rb

```
   Mime::Type.register 'application/pdf', :pdf
```

I simply go to the page like http://localhost:3000/orders/4 and append a .pdf (as per Railscasts). 
http://localhost:3000/orders/4.pdf shows a pdf but no css. Same with Browser's print preview.

Does anyone know how I can debug this further?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to load the stylesheet via HTTP. However, the PDFKit requires a File.

This is taken from the PDFKit source code:

```
  def style_tag_for(stylesheet)
    "<style>#{File.read(stylesheet)}</style>"
  end
```

See the rest of the code at:

https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/blob/master/lib/pdfkit/pdfkit.rb#L105

My suggestion would try edit the show.html.erb with adding:

```
<style> <%= Rails.application.assets['application.css'].to_s %> </style>
```

Or loading it from file. Change your code to this:

```
temp = Tempfile.new("pdf_css_temp")
temp.write(Rails.application.assets['application.css'].to_s)
temp.close
kit.stylesheets << temp.path
```

other_controller.rb

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf {
    html = render_to_string(:template => "show.html.erb")
    kit = PDFKit.new(html)
    temp = Tempfile.new("pdf_css_temp")
    temp.write(Rails.application.assets['application.css'].to_s)
    temp.close
    kit.stylesheets << temp.path
    send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "test_pdf", :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => 'attachment')
    temp.unlink
    return
  }
```

However, the downside of this is that it will write a temporary file each time you generate a PDF. In a production environment you probably want to solve this by using a static file generated by rails.

Comment: So should I change this :  

 kit.stylesheets << "http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/application.css" 
to 
kit.stylesheets << "stylesheets/application.css"

Comment: Do you know if we can check on CLI or someway to check all the stylesheets grabbed by pdfkit?

Comment: If you depend on includes in the application.css like " *= require_tree ." it won't work. You have to get a compiled version.

Comment: I updated the post, I believe that would work out for you. Rails should now compile the application.css

Comment: ok copied all the application.css content into a print.css and included it like this : 
     kit.stylesheets << Rails.root.join('app','assets','stylesheets','print.css')

Comment: Updated again. But this has a negative effect with temporary files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98882/discussion-between-user2511030-and-meeh).

Answer (score 0):

Before I was trying:

```
:css
  #{Rails.application.assets.find_asset('application.scss').to_s}
```

Better if you try:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
```